# Quoted string in templates

Tags: templates, go

I want to put in my html template (actually JavaScript part) null or string with email:

```
var email = null;
// or a string:
var email = "somebody@somewhere.com";
```

But with template

```
var email = {{.Email}};
```

I get quoted string everytime:

```
var email = "null";
var email = "somebody@somewhere.com";
```

How to fix it?

EDIT: here is my code: http://play.golang.org/p/8k4s8dv2PE

You can see Go surrounds string with quotes and removes comment - there is pre or post processing.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your Go code, which you don't provide so it's hard to tell. Are you surrounding the value with quotes in Go?

Comment: Here is the sample: http://play.golang.org/p/8k4s8dv2PE
It doesn't work (you can run it online).

Comment: Firstly, please press the format button before sharing.  It's right next to the share button and makes it more readable.  Secondly, it's documented behavior in html/template.  Here's a cleaned up example showing both:  http://play.golang.org/p/AcySM8UADL

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your code, the best I can do is provide [an example that shows your required functionality](http://play.golang.org/p/kXlahcaMOl).

If I had to take a guess, I'd say the data you were passing in was a string, not a string pointer. A string cannot have a value of nil/null, only a string pointer can. Though that would yield a "", not a "null", ([as demonstrated here](http://play.golang.org/p/23t7tnxJZY)), so I can only imagine that this is something weird you're doing in your code.

To prevent link-rot, I've duplicated the code examples below, though it's worth clicking through the links to see their output.

**Required Functionality**:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "html/template"
)

type TemplateData struct {
    Email *string
}

func main() {

    const temp = "<script>var email = {{.Email}};</script>\n"

    t := template.Must(template.New("email_template").Parse(temp))
    email := "somebody@somewhere.com"
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, TemplateData{
        Email: &email,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, TemplateData{
        Email: nil,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }

}
```

**Trying to use a "null" string**:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "html/template"
)

type TemplateData struct {
    Email string
}

func main() {

    const temp = "<script>var email = {{.Email}};</script>\n"

    t := template.Must(template.New("email_template").Parse(temp))
    email := "somebody@somewhere.com"
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, TemplateData{
        Email: email,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, TemplateData{
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }

}
```

Comment: @demi html/template auto-escapes text contextually. Because the string is in a script context, it is converted to a javascript string. To get a null object, you'll need to pass a literal nil, not a string containing the word "null". See my implementation of your required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using the least amount of editing to your code sample:

```
type TplCtx struct {
  UserEmail *string
}
```

and

```
t.Execute(os.Stdout, &TplCtx{nil})
```