# Go lang templates: always quotes a string and removes comments

Tags: go, go-templates

This Go code always quotes a string: http://play.golang.org/p/8k4s8dv2PE in the template - you can see results. How can I generate `var currentUser = null`? Note it also removes all comments from the code! How is it tuned up? This question is continuation of my [Go: quoted string in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150985/go-quoted-string-in-templates).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `html/template` package is expressly designed to escape values. In your case, you're trying to pass JavaScript code in, rather than a simple value. You can accomplish this by changing the type of `UserEmail` to that of `template.JS`. This type wraps a `string` and expresses the intent that this value is valid JavaScript and should be substituted directly (without quotes) when used in a JavaScript context.

This version of the code does precisely that: http://play.golang.org/p/aNGnFMyY1O

Comment: I may fallback to use `text/template` and escape strings coming into template manually.

Comment: @demi: If you do that, `text/template` has some built-in functions you can use in your template, such as `html` to do html-escaping and `js` to do javascript-escaping. You can use these in your pipelines.