# Insert JavaScript Snippet Inside Template with Beego/GoLang

Tags: javascript, templates, canvas, go

What is the best method to insert a javascript snippet into a template for Golang using the Beego framework?

Currently, I am just adding data to a template:

```
c.Data["Javascript"] = JavasciptStringObject
```

And in a script.tpl file adding insertion points:

```
 var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 canvas.setHeight(571); //todo: Set to height of image
 canvas.setWidth(991);
 {{.JavaScript}}
```

The problem is that it escapes the quotation marks from the string, rather than injecting directly in:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(571); 
canvas.setWidth(991);
"var path = new fabric.Path('M 617 141 L 606 126M 606 126 L 604 127 z', { stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 2, fill: false, originX: 'left', originY: 'top',});canvas.add(path); "
```

Some useful resources include Golang HTML Templating Doc, which apparently Beego models: https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

And this stack overflow seems to be getting closer, I don't think this will work with Beego: [Go lang templates: always quotes a string and removes comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226416/go-lang-templates-always-quotes-a-string-and-removes-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was

```
 import "html/template"

 //within function
 c.Data["Javascript"] = template.JS(JavasciptStringObject)
```

Note: template.JSEscape did not work.